# Using SWIG to create java bindings for C++ classes

Tags: java, c++, interface, swig, multiple-inheritance

With SWIG am able to create simple bindings for my C++ code.

My question here is for multiple inheritance.

Our C++ codebase has a iClass as base class, which acts as interface. Also we have classes that are derived from two classes, one of which is this interface class.

Now my question is can we use SWIG to create bindings for such a codebase, assuming that we can put our class iClass as an Interface in Java.

It is still multiple inheritance but a very specific case of it and is analogous with interface concept of java.

Comment: So, I have two pure virtual classes in I1.h and I2.h and a class Base which inherits from I1 and I2. Now when I try to swig it got the warning I2 ignored. Multiple Inheritance is not supported in Java. SO my question is how can i map it in java. Reason why I see a possibility is because I1 and I2 are analogous to Interface in Java. If i can map them to interfaces my work is done.

Answer (score 1):

The case with SWIG is that it indeed will only extend the first base class you list (in the code example below that would be I1) and omit the rest. Interestingly, the C++ compiled code WILL include all the base methods, they are just not available to the Java JNI wrapper.

Multiple inheritance is another paradigm than interfacing, making it hard to cast / interpret an Object in Java as belonging to a particular interface.

What you can do though - which does feel a tad fugly - is to add a compiler directive to the header file of the class which is inheriting from multiple classes. Like so:

```
class Foo : public I1, I2
{
    public:
        Foo();
        ~Foo();

        #ifdef SWIG
        void aI2Method();
        double aI2Property;
        #endif

    protected:
        void bar();
}
```

When compiling with SWIG, property SWIG is defined. As such the method "aI2Method" and public property "aI2Property" (which for the sake of argument, we assume are defined in base class I2) are used by SWIG and defined in the JNI wrapper for this class "Foo". Just add the public methods / properties in between the conditional directive.

In Java you can then invoke "aI2Method" on Foo or get/set the public "aI2Property"-property, and the native compiled code will invoke these on the I2 base class. Note that this means you don't need to add the same directive including the definitions or function bodies of these methods in the .cpp file of "Foo", as placing it in the header file will suffice. This way, at least the .cpp files remain clean.

Comment: Well this is fugly indeed:) 
My problem is its damn big code base that am talking about. It will take quite a lot of effort this way. Anyways I am thinking to go ahead with the wrappers instead of the whole code base. There are just too many concerns with swig and it will take significant effort  from our end. Wrapper will help me here. And may be SWIG on top of these wrappers. Not a best solution but an easy one.